# Determine the null value in array and get the key array

Tags: php

I had some problem when to post array data:

When I post the data it will be 2 array:

```
Array(1)[
[0]=>1
[1]=>2
[2]=>3
]

Array(2)[
[0]=>1
[1]=>
[2]=>3
]
```

Note that Array2 will be some blank data.

Now I am working until using **array_filter(Array2)** but the question is can i get the key /data from Array1 match to the not null data from Array2?

Maybe it will be some confusing on question, Sorry to my bad language...

Comment: So your output should be `[0 => 1, 2 => 3]`?

Comment: I am thinking to insert the query : insert into table values(array1,array2)

Comment: That is not the answer to my question. What do you want the output to be from your said function/statement?

Comment: the expected output you said just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter `$array1` based on the value of `$array2`, you can use `filter` with third parameter `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` to use the key.

```
$array1 = [1,2,3];
$array2 = [1,null,500];

$newArray1 = array_filter($array1, function ($key) use ($array2) {
        return $array2[$key];
    },ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

$newArray2 = array_filter($array2);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $newArray1 );
print_r( $newArray2 );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 500
)
```

Comment: how can i  do in insert query? "insert into tables values(1,1)", "insert into tables values(1,500)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect` to get non-null values from array1

```
$arr = array(
   1 => array(1,2,3),
   2 => array(1,'',3)
);

$result= array_filter(array_intersect($arr[1],$arr[2]));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Result

```
Array
(
 [0] => 1
 [2] => 3
)
```

Comment: This matches null values and where the values are offset from each other. https://3v4l.org/IfG2a

Comment: @Andreas OP is looking for the values from array1 which have values on same index on array2

Comment: @Andreas read this "can i get the key /data from Array1 match to the not null data from Array2?"

Comment: Yes, and your code does not do that. See the example

Comment: i think this is true answer for now, then can i know how to insert this data: "insert into table values('1','1')","insert into table values('3','3')"

Comment: @Andreas This is based on the OP data

Comment: try INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (column1,column2)
VALUES
    (1,1),
    (3,3)

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is correct:

Use array_intersect_assoc and array filter.
Array filter will remove null values and array_intersect_assoc will find matching in between the two arrays.

Array_intersect_assoc is what you need since it will match keys also and not only values.

```
$res = array_intersect_assoc(array_filter($arr1), array_filter($arr2));
```

See example here: https://3v4l.org/Tp72C
Null values are omitted and the "1" is only matched at key 0 since there is no "1" at position 4 in array2